# Can I travel days after my intended date of travel?

Tags: visas, uk

I applied for a general visitor visa and the date is for 25th but I'l have to go 3days later. Am I allowed to do that and am I allowed to extend my stay with 3 days?

Comment: Country of travel ??

Comment: You are travelling the UK on an entry clearance.  What's important here is [1] has your entry clearance been issued yet?  and [2] is your change in plans reportable or not (per the agreement you signed).  Everything else is irrelevant, please add those details and ask for the question to be reopened.  The lack of those things make your question 'unclear'